# iOS Change Distribution Type for New Release

Tags: ios

I have an app for a business customer that is set for private distribution under Distribution for Business and Education.  I am creating a new release and trying to change the category to allow it to be also in the App Store so that their employees can use their personal phones.  This does not seem to be possible and Apple support told me it can't be done.  My only option is to create an entirely new app because, once approved for private distribution, there is no going back.

I would understand not being able to change it for a released app, but when submitting for review a new release, why can't it be changed at that time.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: It doesn't have to "an entirely new app". It can be the same app with a different bundle ID. Can't it?

Comment: Yeah, but I have to create a whole new store presence for it, and their IT has to create a new entity in their device management software....just a lot of unnecessary work I think.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "unnecessary". It seems to me that you've demonstrated quite clearly that it _is_ necessary.